# Does SELECT DISTINCT differ from SELECT when using a NOT IN clause?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, distinct

My

```
DELETE FROM FOO
WHERE [FOO_KEY] NOT IN
  (
    SELECT [FOO_KEY] FROM BAR
  )
```

query is running shockingly slow. I know that BAR is a very big table, so I'm tempted to write

```
DELETE FROM FOO
WHERE [FOO_KEY] NOT IN
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT [FOO_KEY] FROM BAR
  )
```

but I remember being told that:

1. When `NULL`s aren't a problem (and they're not here) there's hardly any difference between `IN` and `EXISTS`.
2. When using `EXISTS`, you don't need to use `SELECT DISTINCT` and there is no performance reason to do so.

This leaves me with good reason to believe that it is *absolutely guaranteed* that adding `DISTINCT` here will not make a difference. Is that correct?

Comment: `DISTINCT` will only slow the query down. Honestly, I would suggest trying `EXISTS` first; SQL Server can then "short circuit" as soon as it finds a matching row.

Comment: When it comes to actual execution of queries in terms of performance, very very little is "absolutely guaranteed". Even semantically trivial changes might get different plans depending on what path was triggered in the optimizer. The only truly reliable way is comparing execution plans; in this case even an estimated execution plan should do and tell you whether there's a difference or not. Sometimes this can even lead to nasty surprises, for example when finding out that someone turned `BAR` into a view...

Comment: Why go out of your way to use NOT IN here by citing these things that make NOT IN "okay in this case"? Why not just always use NOT EXISTS because it is _always ok_? Anyway I would bet lunch that nothing is slow here because you are using NOT IN or because you are (or are not) using DISTINCT. The slowness is probably because the delete itself is being blocked, or is incurring a lot of activity, or there are triggers, or you're scanning BAR and it is massive, or the log is very slow for _all_ DML, or any combination of these... grasping at distinct instead of inspecting the plan is silly.

Comment: In addition, why even ask a question where the answer, whether adding distinct would make a difference, is something you can very easily just go and try? Just compare the execution plans of both with and without and note any difference in logical reads and cpu.

Comment: @Stu Because even if I find that the execution plan is the same, that doesn't prove that the two plans were **guaranteed** to be identical.

Comment: The problem is that there are no guarantees when it comes to performance. You can ask whether or not the queries are semantically identical (and they are), meaning the outcome in terms of rows will be the same, but unfortunately this is no guarantee at all of identical performance, and you're not going to get any either. Even if a SQL Server engineer popped in and gave it to you, it could be invalidated tomorrow. Maybe the engine will optimize out the `DISTINCT`, maybe it won't. Maybe not optimizing it out actually performs better based on your indexing and duplicates, maybe it doesn't.

Comment: @AaronBertrand In my defence, the plan that the activity monitor is showing looks extremely sensible. My indexes are clearly being used. The only oddity is that one clustered index scan says it estimates that it has 48,805,700 rows to check. ...I accept that I'm clearly clutching at straws.

Comment: Hopefully you don't mean [this Activity Monitor](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/10/why-i-dont-use-sql-server-activity-monitor/).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Actually, I did. Am I profoundly clueless? Regardless, making an index seemed to be the solution, even though SQL Server didn't suggest any.

Comment: That's not what anybody said. There are just... better ways to manage SQL Server performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a functional point of view, the queries with or without `DISTINCT` are identical (they would delete the same set of rows).

From a performance point of view, I am certain that SQL Server will always produce the same execution plan for both queries (but I cannot prove this).

For other database engines, this may be different. See:

- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/optimizing-group-by/
- https://www.quora.com/Should-I-use-DISTINCT-in-a-subquery-when-using-IN
- https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/tuning/ctuntransform867165.html